# How to make Wordpress permalinks ignore custom url rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, locale

i'm currently working on a wordpress site that needs to have the option to be offered in french. i've found a way to make the theme work with the fr_FR po and mo files when i add a querystring variable `l`. i.e.

`site.tld` will yield the vanilla english site, while `site.tld/?l=fr` will activate the following code in my functions.php to serve the french translation:

```
<?php
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale
add_filter( 'locale', 'set_my_locale' );
function set_my_locale( $lang ) {
    if ("fr" == substr(strtolower(trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['l'])))), 0, 2)) {
        // set language to french
        return "fr_FR";
    } else {
        // return original locale
        return $lang;
    }
}
?>
```

this setup is already working. my question is: how do i rewrite the url so instead of `site.tld/?l=fr` i can just prepend the folder structure with `fr` i.e. `site.tld/fr/`?

so like if there's a page `site.tld/portoflio/autumn/` in english, `site.tld/fr/portfolio/autumn/` will spit out the french one. i got this idea from the apple website, where the language is always prepended to the folder structure.

i can already make this happen with an external redirect in htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ^[a-z]{2}/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?l=$1 [R,L]
```

this works, but once i remove the `R` flag it serves the french-translated 404 not found isntead. i'm guessing what i did is messing-up with wordpress' rewrite rules because i need to use pretty permalinks. right now i'm set to use `Month and name` (`/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`) in the admin general options.

my question is, how do i make wordpress ignore the `/fr/` part and still serve the correct page/post/etc?

is this even possible? am i on the right track here? i need your help especially doing what's WISE and not just what's NICE. i tried this http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api but for the life of me i can't make it work. :/

---

**UPDATE**: ok, so here's some progress taking cue from @relu below:

i made sure my rules were canned from `.htaccess`

i then added the rules from @relu but in the following way, because Relu's always sent me to the same address without the `/fr`:

```
<?
    // http://pmg.co/custom-wordpress-shortlinks
    add_action( 'init', 'pmgtut_add_rewrites' );
    function pmgtut_add_rewrites() {
        add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-z]{2})/?$', 'index.php?l=$matches[1]', 'top' );
        add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$', 'index.php?l=$matches[1]&q=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'pmgtut_query_vars', 10, 1 );
    function pmgtut_query_vars( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = 'l';
        return $vars;
    }
?>
```

now the `/fr` stays in the address bar, so that's a good thing, but two problems persist:

1. wordpress is serving me the main index page. seems like it's not using the `&q=$matches[2]` part of the rule; and
2. the locale still doesn't get set properly. i checked if the variable `l` is getting fed, so i added `echo 'l: $l';` after `$l = get_query_var('l');` and interestingly i get two echoes: one `l:` and another `l: fr` right after that. is the `locale` filter being run twice? seems like the first time it doesn't see the value of the queryvar, and then there seems to be a second time that it outputs `l:` with `fr` already in there.. at the end of the day the locale still doesn't get changed.

aaaah help.

---

**FINAL UPDATE**: in my last breath of frustration i searched again, and found this plugin qtranslate. does what i need. thanks y'all, esp to @relu's epic effort and stayin pow'r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?l=$matches[1]&q=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the l var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'l');
    return $vars;
}
```

Haven't tested this, it may need some tweaking, but this is the way to do it.

I've basically adapted the version found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite).

It also registers the "**l**" query var so you can get it's value by calling: [get_query_var](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'set_my_locale' );
function set_my_locale( $lang ) {
    $l = get_query_var('l');

    if ("fr" == $l) {
        // set language to french
        return "fr_FR";
    } else {
        // return original locale
        return $lang;
    }
}
```

**UDATE:** Ignore the above!

---

Remove the `my_insert_query_vars()` filter and replace it with:

```
function register_rewrite_tag() {
        add_rewrite_tag('%l%', '([a-z]{2})');
}
add_action('init', 'register_rewrite_tag');
```

Here are also the updated rewrites for pages and posts, I've looked at WordPress' `$wp_rewrite->rules` and adapted them to fit this special case:

```
function pmgtut_add_rewrites() {
        add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-z]{2})/?$', 'index.php?l=$matches[1]', 'top' );
        add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-z]{2})/(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?l=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]', 'top' ); // Pages
        add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?l=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]', 'top' ); // Posts
}
```

Comment: wow sorry i just saw this. thanks!! ok, so when i add these, they just take me back to the link without the `/fr` hmm.. any thoughts? am clueless atm

Comment: Did you remove those rules from .htaccess? They aren't needed!

Comment: yeap, did so.. i also made sure only wordpress' rwrules are in there..  will let you know asap when i get it to work. in the meantime lemme know too if there's sum'n else we could do. thanks much, 'preciate it man!

Comment: question: what's the `q` in `&q=$matches[2]` for?

Comment: hey @relu kindly check my update at the end of the question. thanks munch

Comment: ok. i tried. for the past 4.5 hrs. i can't make it work. in my last breath of frustration i searched again, and found this plugin qtranslate. does what i need. thank you soooo much for the stellar effort. how do i give you 1000 reputation points? :D

Comment: Oh, so what you really wanted was something to manage translations? I used WPML on some websites and it does the job really well, but may be overkill for your case. Maybe qTranslate is just right, glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

maybe out of topic but here's another rewrite rule for languages of the form; en_us/ or jp/

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}|^[a-z]{2})/?$', 'index.php?l=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```